# How can I convert to greyscale the background image in CSS?

Tags: css

I have an html section,

```
<div id="home">
    ...
</div>
```

and the following css applied,

```
  #home {
      background: url(../images/main.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      display: table;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
  }
```

My question is, how can I select the background image, which was set by CSS as background,  so I can apply a filter? The only thing I want to do is to grayscale the background image. Which is the appropriate selector for a property?

Comment: Exact duplicate. Please, search before ask a question.

Answer (score -3):

You have the `background-image` css property

```
background-image: url("test.gif");
```